In Excel how to find days from dates in a specific cell date minus date in same row column without specified cell
Here is an example of what I am trying to do:
    A          Date         C        D
   ------   --------   ------   --------
1  Today    [=TODAY()]

   A          Date         C        D
  ------   --------   ------   --------
2  iuiouiu   1/2/23    iuoui    =DAYS(Date1,ROW(Date))???
3  iuiouiu   8/8/23    iuoui
4  iuiouiu   12/2/23   iuoui

I want column D to tell me the days from B1 minus A2 but without using A2, like referencing the same row in a different column "Date".  Reason being that I need to filter a large table that changes length data. Running the formula with specific cell address would be too hectic. The columns are consistent, and I only need a portion of the date range on a smaller set.

It would be helpful if you could further clarify what your desired result is. Guessing you may want something like this =DAYS($B$1, B2) in D2, which would then give you the number of days relative to today for each date.

In simpler words, I like column d to look  like this:
=DAYS(Date1,B2)

In simpler words, I like column D to look like this:
=DAYS(Date1,Date2)
=DAYS(Date1,Date3)
=DAYS(Date1,Date4)
...
Date1 is a constant and stays as is, but I don't want to put Date2, Date3, Date4. Instead, use a reference to the cell in that same row under Column Date.

That is in fact what my example does. =DAYS($B$1, B2) locks the "Date1" reference to cell B1, and then as you fill down, Date2/Date3/Date4 will be B2/B3/B4 respectively.

=DAYS(TODAY(), B2) would also work

I think you are referring to something like this for D2 cell:
=DAYS($B$1,INDIRECT("R"&ROW()&"C"&(COLUMN()-2),FALSE))


thank you @leoinfo this worked:
=DAYS(B1,INDIRECT("R"&ROW()&"C"&(COLUMN()-1),FALSE))
